# How to remove file name & parameter from URL, but keep parameter value using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

**Current URL:** http://broom.xyz/index.php?tag=C/santa

**GOAL URL:** http://broom.xyz/C/santa

> Note: The Tag 'C/santa' is a single dynamic value.
>   It can change to anything like 'F/fanta' or 'M/Manta'.

**My Code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

**This Code Generates A 500 Internal Server Error. Here Is The Error Log:**

> [Fri Apr 07 13:33:10.469218 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4202] [client
>   47.11.122.64:52755] /var/www/html/workspace/broom/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not
>   included in the server configuration [Fri Apr 07 13:40:31.595944 2017]
>   [core:alert] [pid 4185] [client 47.11.122.64:53076]
>   /var/www/html/workspace/broom/.htaccess: Invalid command
>   'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not
>   included in the server configuration

Comment: Can you post what you have tried to rewrite the url?

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check. I have no clue how to achieve it. Tried all solutions at Stackoverflow.

Comment: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Rule's pattern does not match the uri **C/Santa**  but matches **CSanta** This is because  you have excluded the **/** in your pattern **^([^/]*)** . You need to fix it so that it can accept any chars in the uri.

Replace your RewriteRule line with this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Comment: No. It didn't work. Gives a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Please check your error log for info about the 500internal server error.

Comment: [Fri Apr 07 13:33:10.469218 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4202] [client 47.11.122.64:52755] /var/www/html/workspace/broom/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Fri Apr 07 13:40:31.595944 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4185] [client 47.11.122.64:53076] /var/www/html/workspace/broom/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Your server is causing this error due to one of the following reasons :
1) You misspelled the The directive **RewriteEngine** try changing it to **RewriteEngine on** if that was a typo.
2)Mod-rewrite isnt enabled , Check if mod-rewrite is enabled on your server.